# Using delimiters to split an equation and run it

Tags: java, delimiter

So I am doing a project for a class of mine and it involves the use of delimiters and other scanner methods. However I've been doing a lot of research and the book we have does not clearly explain as to how it works. So after several headaches and trying to understand I figured I'd ask here (EDIT: This is something somewhat similar I found [relating to delimiters and splitting number sequences] to what my teacher was asking me and thought it would be adequate to ask it here. So before I get accused of doing my homework on here I wanted to clarify)

Here's what I have typed so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class addUp
{
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   { 
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : "); 
      String s = kb.nextLine( ); 
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(s); 

      /* sc.useDelimiter("\\s*"); With some help and research I found 
         out that the \\s* actually causes every character to be split 
         apart. so 33 is 3 3 */

      int sum = sc.nextInt();
      while(sc.hasNextInt( )) 
      {
         String operator = sc.next();
         int value = sc.nextInt();

         if(operator.equals("-"))
         {
            sum = sum - value;
         }

         else if(operator.equals("+"))
         {
            sum = sum + value;
         }
      } 
      System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum); 
   } 
}
```

And my last attempt got me a weird output:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java addUp

Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137
Sum is: 8

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Now I don't know a ton and I'm sure if I came in with something more complicated than the progress of what we've been through would not be appreciated (since I know I've seen some people answer other questions that is way over my understanding). So keep it dumbed down for me if you can XD. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a debugger?  yuo should step through this program one line at a time and verify the value of sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code at the moment is that your while loop is checking for `while(sc.hasNextInt( ))`, but it's expecting an operator.  Change that to `while(sc.hasNext()` and you should be ok.

Additionally, when facing problems like this, try running your code in a debugger and stepping through it.  You'd see pretty quickly that it didn't enter into the while loop and that would help you diagnose the problem.  If you don't have access to a debugger, just put in some `System.out.println()` statements.

**UPDATE**

So, I ran your code in a debugger (after changing the while loop as I described), and the first thing I noticed was that the first call to `sc.nextInt()` returns `3`, not `33`, because of the reason [H L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3303818/h-l) explained.  Having removed the call to `setDelimeter`, the code runs fine.  It should now look like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class addUp
{
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   { 
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : "); 
      String s = kb.nextLine( ); 
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(s); 

      //sc.useDelimiter("\\s*"); <-- don't do this
      int sum = sc.nextInt();
      while(sc.hasNext( )) // <-- not hasNextInt
      {
         String operator = sc.next();
         int value = sc.nextInt();

         if(operator.equals("-"))
         {
            sum = sum - value;
         }

         else if(operator.equals("+"))
         {
            sum = sum + value;
         }
      } 
      System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum); 
   } 
}
```

And outputs:

```
Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137
Sum is: 1249
```

Again, you should have spotted this if you stepped through your code in a debugger (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, jdb, etc).

Comment: Hmmm. So I used your advice and H L's advice above and saw that it would start on + 33 but once I put in if/else I suddenly got an `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException` error. I don't understand how once I have it check if sc.next(stored in a separate variable).equals("+") then have it run sum = sum - sc.nextInt (also in a separate variable) would cause it to have an error :/

Comment: For some reason I changed the names of the variables and it suddenly worked? Don't know what went wrong with it in the first place but at least it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out last night. I was getting frustrated and tired at trying to understand (which I accidentally miss things occasionally). After I was able to get some sleep I could see with new eyes and your advice was very helpful, thank you. Our class uses jGrasp but I might try to look around for other programs (If you know any great for people learning and not too complicated would be great) since I didn't fully understand the whole jGrasp debugging feature until now. So sorry if I seemed to be irritable and ignoring you, I wasn't try to be.

Comment: No worries, we've all stared at code looking for a bug until it starts looking like the Matrix's source!

I've not used jGRASP.  The industry standard IDEs are Eclipse and IntelliJ.  The former is completely free, the latter has a free community edition with reduced feature set (although probably fine for your course).  However, if everyone in your class are using the same tool, then it's probably worth persevering with it.

Answer (score 1):

**First Problem** (Apparently corrected in an edit to the quesiton)

You call `sc.next()` in every `if` statement. Call it once, and then use the value when you need it. If you keep calling it, you'll keep eating your input!

```
String op = sc.next();

if (op.equals('-') {}
else if (op.equals('+') {}
else {}
```

**Second Problem**

You  never initialize `sum` to the first number. You skip the first number completely! Start off like this to make sure you consume the first `int` before you consume the first operator.

`int sum = sc.nextInt();`

**Third Problem**

`hasNextInt()` only returns `true` if the next token is an `int`. It returns `false` if the next token is an operator like `"+"` or `"-"`. Change your while to loop on `hasNext()`.

The last fix may cause you to consume a `"/n"` or some other line seperator nonsense on your last iteration of the loop. as it stands, it looks like this will only cause you to print the sum twice. That seems like something you should be able to solve on your own.

Rather than making me edit my answer four MORE times, try to do this on paper, going in circles for the while loop. Consume an int. Consume an operator. Consume an int. Consume an operator. Consume an int. If you break that order, your logic isn't in the right order. Know the logic before you even try to write code.

Go read the [Javadoc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to see what each method you are calling actually does. Learn about [Streams in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html) so you understand how they work.

Comment: I tried that before but I got a whole bunch of errors:  `----jGRASP exec: java addUp

Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at addUp.main(addUp.java:28)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.`

Comment: You should never hit the last `else` to begin with. It didn't work before because you were consuming too much input before you ever got that far.

Comment: Well I made the changes yet output I get is equal to just the first number instead of the actual sum. The project itself actually calls for it to be able to tell if the first number has a negative sign also (its meant so you can input anything and it'll work, not just the example. I'll edit my main post after that to clarify) so I don't know if the nextInt() would really work for that.

Comment: Updated the example so you can see

Comment: @Jgoodwyn Updated my answer so you can hopefully start to think for yourself. StackOverflow is not a homework service.

Comment: @Jgoodwyn You have some nerve. I was trying to motivate you by pointing you to places where you can learn, and each time you edit your question such that my comments are taken out of context. If you find that questions you post have multiple problems, you have not asked a good question. Narrow the focus to fewer lines of code and ask a more specific question. It's obvious that you didn't bother to read the posting guidelines (and you STILL haven't, judging by your edits).

Comment: Actually you advice helped and I was trying to figure it out on my own. Yet the thing I didn't realize what that the delimiter, \\s*, was actually splitting each character. (It's kind of hard to ultimately figure out the source of my issues when new to the subject and not having any luck with research before I made this question) I generally don't want to post something similar to a project I was tasked for help but thought it was a great resource to try to learn how this feature works through a similar project online. Next time I'll try to be more considerate.

Comment: whoa there. Didn't mean to irritate you. I realized that my wording was a little harsher than I wished so I deleted my comment. as you can see. I posted it more as a, "Can you help me understand how this works. Still new to everything so make it easy on me. Thanks" The fact that it eventually changed into something more wasn't my intentions. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You call the `next()` and `nextInt()` methods multiple times within the while loop which consumes too much of our input.
2. The sum is initialized to 0 and the very first operand is omitted.
3. Only the last `else` block is executed because you compare strings with characters (single quotes instead of double quotes) which always evaluates to false.

Code:

```
// WRONG: sc.useDelimiter("\\s*");
int sum = sc.nextInt();  // consume the first token, must be an integer
while (sc.hasNext()) {   // as long as there are more tokes, do the following
    String operator = sc.next();  // read next token, must be a + or - sign
    int operand = sc.nextInt();   // read next token, must be an integer again

    // depending on the arithmetic operator we update the sum variable
    if (operator.equals("-")) {
        sum = sum - operand;
    } else if (operator.equals("+")) {
        sum = sum + operand;
    } else {
        // if the operator variable contains something else than a + or - sign
        // we throw an exception. In general this is the preferred way to avoid
        // that the software changes into an undefined state.
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown operator: " + operator);
    }
}
System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: I tried this but all I get for my output/sum is 8 instead of 1249 (the actual sum for the example integers)

Comment: ...caused by the delimiter pattern. Comment out the line `sc.useDelimiter("\\s*");` and it works.

Comment: ...and it still doesn't work. I get the same output as before. even if I cut out the delimiter statement completely or make ever character a token with `sc.useDelimiter("");` its the same. Though I wouldnt understand as to how \\s* would be an issue since its zero or more whitespace

Comment: If you use the `\\s*` pattern as delimiter, the pattern will match also if there are no white spaces between two characters. The \s* means zero or multiple white spaces (see Kleene star operator). - The `next()` methods return only a single character.

Comment: You might replace your while loop with the following code snippet so you can see what's happening here: `while (sc.hasNext()) { System.out.println(sc.next()); }`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Last night I was having a lot of frustration from working on this for so long time with no luck in research. I guess I didn't realize that the \\s* would also split each character. Helps a lot I appreciate it